# Postgres bulk insert control errors

Tags: postgresql, exception, insert, schema, bulk

Is there any way to control errors in a bulk execution with a `PostgreSQL` script? I'm trying to migrate data from one table to another, and what I need is that, in case of failure of any record, instead of stopping the script execution, the failed data is saved in a new error table.
I've seen a workaround that works with keys-found https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/311280/is-it-possible-to-call-a-function-using-the-on-conflict-event but it doesn't work for me.

My script is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table(id, code)
SELECT uuid_generate_v4(), t.code
FROM sch.tab t
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Instead of `DO NOTHING`, could a function be called to insert the failed record (id and code) into another table?

Comment: Not currently. In the yet as unreleased next version of Postgres(17) there will be that option for `COPY`. See [COPY SAVE_ERROR_TO](https://www.depesz.com/2024/02/07/waiting-for-postgresql-17-add-new-copy-option-save_error_to-rename-copy-option-from-save_error_to-to-on_error/) from depesz.

Comment: Write a function in plpgsql with an exeption handler. That's how you had to do it in the old days, when `ON CONFLICT` was not available at all. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: No! At least not with the current version. However, and unfortunately you neglected to disclose your Postgres version, with v15 and above I believe  the would be available with the [Merge](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-merge.html). statement.

Comment: thanks to all. Finally we had to commit each row  (with an exception for save tha error log in a new table) instead of doing a bulk insert